# Code analysis only shows CSxxx and IDExxx notes I see no CAxxx messages

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2022, roslyn-code-analysis

How do I get code analysis to show me IDisposables not disposed. It doesn't seem like any of the CAxxx rules are used. I tried adding the nuget package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers, that doesn't seem to make a difference. Then I added Microsoft Analysis Services Projects extension (vsix), and nothing.

I build the solution, I clicked Analyze -> Run Code Analysis -> On Solution etc.

It's a non-SDK referencing project, I tried to edit the .csproj file to reference the sdk, but just had a lot of issues so that I gave up on that idea.

I know there are some IDisposable's that are not disposed but I don't get any warnings about that.

Comment: Are you using https://www.nuget.org/packages/IDisposableAnalyzers?

Comment: Which version of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers are you using? Have you used Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers before? If you have used Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers, you can read the following link to understand the differences between the two analyzers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/net-analyzers-faq?view=vs-2019

Comment: @PiersMyers No I'm using nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT On this project I have not used FxCop. The problem is NetAnalyzers doesn't seem to do anything apart from what Visual Studio is already doing

Comment: There is an Analyzers level in Code Analyzers in your project properties. What is your Analyzers level?